# Is map<int, list> in C++ possible?

Tags: c++

I want to have a linkedlist for each key in the map in C++.

Comment: Of course it's possible. `std::map` is generic.

Comment: Sure, `std::map< Key, std::list< Value > >`.

Comment: list<node> mylist;
map<int,mylist> map;   Is not working

Comment: No, you supply *types* in the template argument list, not objects. `int` is a type, `mylist` is not.

Comment: but i need to have a linked list created to each and every key in the map

Comment: This is an example of a *basic* question (a question from a novice) - not a *false* question.  It is just a fine question.  I do not think it should have been closed unless it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `std::map<int, std::list<SomeType>>` is possible in C++.

Have a look at [ideone](http://www.ideone.com), which is useful for testing simple things such as this.

Comment: That does not work, `std::list` is a template and needs a template parameter, something like I wrote in my comment on the question.